# How to get distance in kilometer when pass in 2 value (langtitude and longitude) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table in mysql call BRANCH

```
===============================
Branch_id latitude longitude
===============================
1         3.109421  101.622913
2         3.101121  101.644913
```

How can i select kilometer calculation from this table when I pass in my current location latitude / longitude?

Example:

If I pass in my current location = 3.122221  101.343913

```
============================================
Branch_id latitude longitude   distance(km)
============================================
1         3.109421  101.622913   0.4
2         3.101121  101.644913   0.6
```

**Edited (Solved):**

```
SELECT p.title,p.subtitle,p.desc,p.image,p.promotion_id,p.merchant_id,p.date_from,p.date_to,m.merchant_name,p.view,mb.latitude,mb.longitude,
    (6371 * acos (cos( radians(3.158704)) * cos( radians(mb.latitude)) 
        * cos( radians(mb.longitude) - radians(101.713963)) + sin(radians(3.158704)) 
        * sin( radians(mb.latitude)))) AS distance
FROM merchant_branch as mb
left join merchant m on mb.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
left join promotion p on p.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
where p.promotion_id is not null order by distance asc
```

Comment: Yep that's a standard Haversine formula. Google  Developer has a good write about it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator

> Here's the SQL statement that finds the closest 20 locations within a
>   radius of 25 miles to the -33, 151 coordinate. It calculates the
>   distance based on the latitude/longitude of that row and the target
>   latitude/longitude, and then asks for only rows where the distance
>   value is less than 25, orders the whole query by distance, and limits
>   it to 20 results. To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace
>   3959 with 6371.

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Comment: Hi SyntaxGoonoo, I get what I want and thanks for sharing more here.!